# Is there anyway I could count the visitors for a specific file in the public folder?

Tags: laravel, counter, traffic, visitor-pattern

Currently I'm using laravel, and as you know there are many ways to count the visitors for a single page (hits on routes). But I want also to count the visitors for an image or a pdf file in the public folder, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bypass the route to the file location using a proxy URL from your application. Then serve the files using the proxy URL to access the file.

For example: If you have a pdf file accessible at `yourdomain.com/public/some-file.pdf` create a proxy URL for the same something like `yourdomain.com/proxy/some-file.pdf`.

In your routes file create the corresponding route. Note the last part is dynamic and should identify your file.

```
Route::get('/proxy/{fileName}', [DefaultController::class, 'proxy'])
```

In your `DefaultController.php` file do the necessary logging of counts & then serve your original file as a response.

```
public function proxy($fileName) {
  ***your logic to increase visit count. db addition or something
  $pathToFile = Storage::path($fileName);
  return response()->file($pathToFile);
}
```

Comment: It still has to go through a route, is there anyway I could count the visitors using the exact url "yourdomain.com/public/some-file.pdf"?

I mean.. if someone reach the pdf file through a search engine, it will skip the proxy route and the app won't count it :(

Comment: You cant do that directly from laravel. As the file is being served directly by apache or nginx. I am not an expert at that side, but if there Is a means it should come from that side only.

Better option would be to do the above and prevent absolute URL from being served.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is to have routes that return the stream of pdf/image. That way you can use the same method that you use for pages. It could be through $request->ip or something. The downside is, you have to remake all image/pdf links on your pages to redirect to route instead of asset path or whatever you use.